# `vectorResource` throws RuntimeException when ProGuard applies optimizations

Tags: proguard, android-jetpack-compose

I am [using Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha09 with Kotlin 1.4.21](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup). I use [`vectorResource` to load an `ImageVector` from resources](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop).

All works fine in the design previews and for debug builds. However, when I build a release build with ProGuard, I get the following exception at runtime:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1<VectorGraphic> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
    at androidx.compose.ui.autofill.AndroidAutofillDebugUtilsKt.vectorResource(AndroidAutofillDebugUtils.kt:142)
    at ...
```

After a long tedious process trying to identify differences between release and debug which may cause this, I have discovered that [disabling optimization in ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) using `-dontoptimize` 'solves' this issue.

**What exactly causes this discrepancy in behavior?** Is this a bug in, Jetpack Compose, ProGuard, or in my configuration of ProGuard?

Comment: Relevant, ProGuard optimizations are known to cause problems: _"Be prepared however, that it might introduce new and difficult to diagnose bugs, so use it with caution and if anything isn’t working, be sure to disable certain optimizations or disable the use of the optimizing config altogether."_ https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9

Comment: I could not recreate this error in Jetpack Compose 1.0.2. Don't know whether it is related or due to other changes.